# How do you put an authentication token on URL as query parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, json, url-encoding

I'm doing a PayPal Express Checkout on my ASP.Net MVC site.

The site uses token authentication so I'm trying to put the token on the PayPal return URL as a query parameter.

I have a handler that intercepts all requests to my site and extracts the token from the URL or the request header.

Works fine getting it from the header but I get the following exception when its a query parameter.  I get the token from my claims principal and don't do any encoding/decoding.  I've tried [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743160/how-do-i-encode-and-decode-a-base64-string) but had no luck (same exception occurs).

```
System.ArgumentException was caught
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Jwt10204: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler' cannot read this string: '{really long token}'.
The string needs to be in compact JSON format, which is of the form: '<Base64UrlEncodedHeader>.<Base64UrlEndcodedPayload>.<OPTIONAL, Base64UrlEncodedSignature>'.
  Source=System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
  StackTrace:
       at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(String jwtEncodedString)
       at {our namespace}.Providers.JwtTokenServiceProvider.GetToken(String value)
       at {our namespace}.TokenAuthorisationController.Post(TokenRequest request)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that PayPal appending another string (that look like a PayPal Express Checkout token) on then end of the URL with a comma as a delimiter instead of the "&" symbol.

So I solved the issue by removing the comma character and the extra characters after the comma to extra my JWT token.